# Is it Possible to Place An Image In Pygame When The Mouse Button Has Been Clicked?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I have an issue that I just cant seem to figure out with searching or my own knowledge.

Basically, I have a program that makes an image (in this case ball_r.gif) follow the mouse cursor. (program is below)

```
import pygame as pg




pg.init()
# use an image you have (.bmp  .jpg  .png  .gif)
image_file = "ball_r.gif"



black = (0,0,0)
sw = 800
sh = 800



screen = pg.display.set_mode((sw, sh))
pg.display.set_caption('testprogram')
image = pg.image.load(image_file).convert()



start_rect = image.get_rect()
image_rect = start_rect
running = True
while running:
    event = pg.event.poll()
    keyinput = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keyinput[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
        raise SystemExit
    elif event.type == pg.QUIT:
        running = False
    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
        image_rect = start_rect.move(event.pos)

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(image, image_rect)
    pg.display.flip()
```

Basically, what I want to be able to do, is when the left mouse button is clicked, place that image where the cursor was clicked - But the catch is that I need to be able to place as many as I want AND still have the image follow the cursor.

I hope this is possible...

_MouseBatteries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to create another `Surface` object that has the stamped images. I've provided the working code. I've also cleaned it up a bit.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

# use an image you have (.bmp  .jpg  .png  .gif)
image_file = "ball_r.gif"

black = (0,0,0)
sw = 800
sh = 800

screen = pg.display.set_mode((sw, sh))
pg.display.set_caption('testprogram')
image = pg.image.load(image_file).convert()

start_rect = image.get_rect()
image_rect = start_rect
running = True

stamped_surface = pg.Surface((sw, sh))

while running:
    event = pg.event.poll()
    keyinput = pg.key.get_pressed()

    if keyinput[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
        raise SystemExit

    elif event.type == pg.QUIT:
        running = False

    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
        image_rect = start_rect.move(event.pos)

    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        stamped_surface.blit(image, event.pos)

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(stamped_surface, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(image, image_rect)
    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for, and helped me a lot!